# Reason for not being a topology

Tags: general-topology

If $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ and $Y$ is endowed with a topology, then the weakest topology on $X$ such that $f$ is continuous is generated by the basis $A=\{f^{-1}(U): U $is open in $Y\}$. I cannot understand why $A$ itself is not a topology?

Comment: You're right, $A$ is already a topology.

Comment: Then why do we call A as the basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the pedagogic reason for making this definition is that the more usual setup is that we have a collection of functions $(f_i:X\to Y_i)_{I\in I}$, and we are interested in the weakest topology on $X$ making all the $f_i$ continuous. This the topology generated by the **sub**basis
$$ \{ f_i^{-1}(U) \mid i\in I, \text{$U$ open in Y_i}\}. $$
Why your source chose to call $A$ a basis, rather than a subbasis,  isn't clear to me.

Comment: Why they didn't call it a sub-basis is clear - not only is it a basis, it's actually a topology.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I see where you're coming from. I have no idea what the source is or where the discussion was heading. If they're aiming for the general case I do think it's something of a distraction to point out that in this case,  coincidentally, you happen to get a topology.